# Multiple markers at this line - Syntax error (eclipse)

Tags: c, eclipse, i2c

i create a header file for i2c, the origin from Peter Fleury. i rewrite in eclipse and get error warning "Multiple markers at this line - Syntax error - expected identifier or '(' before 'unsigned'" in second line of list program below

```
>#define    i2c_read(ack)   (ack) ? i2c_readAck() : i2c_readNak();
>
>unsigned char  i2c_read (unsigned char ack);
```

anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve?
If you preprocess the #define macro you'll get:

```
unsigned char (unsigned char ack) ? i2c_readAck() : i2c_readNak();;
```

This isn't a legal C. I'm not familiar with i2c, and I don't know what you are trying to do. If you are trying to declare a new variable and initialize it with a value (and call the correct method), you should:

```
#define  i2c_read(ack)   (ack) ? i2c_readAck() : i2c_readNak()
unsigned char new_var = i2c_read (ack);
```

Note that I'm assuming ack is defined somewhere else. If you are trying to achieve something else, please specify it in your question.
Also note I removed one semicolon from the '#define'. It is a common mistake, which typically only generate a warning or go unnoticed.

Oh, and if you are trying the declare a function, then it should have a different name than the macro.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a macro and declared a function with same name.
Perhaps you should change the macro name or function name.